# PowerShell: select string in a line in a multi-lines input file

Tags: powershell

I have an input file `dummy.build` with content:

```
<property name="componentA.version" value="3.50.0.7"/>
<property name="componentB.version" value="3.50.0.12"/>
```

How do I use **PowerShell** to get the version of component A, (`3.50.0.7` in this case) ?

Comment: Use `Get-Content` to get the content of your file and then parse it using regular expressions, or the `-split` function and substrings. Have a go and then come back here if you're stuck.

Comment: `$Version=gc .\dummy.build|?{$_ -match 'componentA.*value="([0-9.]+)"'}|%{$matches[1]}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
Get-Content dummy.build |
    ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -match '"(?<Component>\w+)\.version\".*\"(?<Version>(\d+\.){3}\d+)\"')
        {
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                Component = $matches.Component
                Version = $matches.Version
            }
        }
    }
```

This will produce a custom object for each matching line, with the component name and version as properties:

```
Component  Version  
---------  -------  
componentA 3.50.0.7 
componentB 3.50.0.12
```